# Replace special character in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace, special-characters

I changed my forum from kunena to phpbb3. Problem is that my old forum (that is indexed in google) has special characters in urls. I want to keep my urls, so old link works with new forum - but only when special characters are replace with normal letters.

I need to use htaccess to convert characters on the fly.

for example

```
ą => a
ę => e
ś => s
ć => c
```

so in words letters will be replaced like this

po**ś**ciel**ó**wka => po**s**ciel**o**wka

Can someone help me with that?
p.s. sorry for bad English ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)ą(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ę(.*)$ /$1e$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ś(.*)$ /$1s$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ć(.*)$ /$1c$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ó(.*)$ /$1o$2 [L,R=301]
```

etc.

This redirects a URL like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/pościelówka
```

and redirects the browser to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/poscielowka
```

as long as the `/poscielowka` URI actually exists.

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(

i tried url
`.... coś.html` 

I'vegot 404 with that text
`/coÅ›.html was not found on this server.`

Comment: It works :D

I add some lines like: RewriteRule ^(.*)Å›(.*)$ /$1s$2 [L,R=301] but it works now. Thank You :D

Comment: @user2757017 Weird, that looks like some unicode encoding issue either with htaccess file or apache

Comment: Yes it's some encoding problem. What is wierd different browser shows different characters. I add few lines to htaccess for every encoding, and it works like charm now.

Comment: To avoid permanent cache problems I edited flag as `[R=301,L,E=nocache:1]` followed by these lines: `Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=nocache` and  `Header always set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=nocache`

Comment: what about replacing **%20** with **+**? `RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301]` is not working

Comment: I've solved my problem with this:
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/u003d(.*)$                              /$1=$2   [L,R=301]

 
 thank you!