# mod_rewrite Replace underscores with plus sign and pass data to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently switched to Wordpress and I dont want to lose some of the old pages.
The old website had pages using the following URL format

```
domain.name/gallery/word1_word2_word3_wordX.html
```

I need these links to be converted to:

```
domain.name/?s=word1+word2+word3+wordX&post_type=product
```

Basically I need to get everything after gallery/, remove .html, replace the underscores with plus sign and pass this to the new URL format between domain.name/?s= and &post_type=product

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279758/2057919

Comment: Actually that was the first method I tried to modify for my situation, but my mod_rewrite abilities are very limited and the result wasnt successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with this a bit and came up with a solution that works:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Note: This line is important! Without it, your URLs will look like example.com/home/you/public_html/gallery/etc, which is bad.
RewriteBase /

# Replace any _ with + and redirect
RewriteRule ^gallery\/(.*)_(.*) gallery/$1+$2 [R=301]
# Replace gallery/whatever.html with /?s=whatever&post_type=product
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)\.html /?s=$1&post_type=product [R=301]
```

This turns

```
http://example.com/gallery/foo_bar_baz_bam.html
```

into

```
http://example.com/?s=foo+bar+baz+bam&post_type=product
```

I drew on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675855/2057919) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279758/2057919) to come up with this; you may find those helpful, as well.

**Note:** This does a redirect for each stage of the rewrite (one per `_` and one for the final transformation). In theory, it's possible to do only one redirect by using `[N]` instead of `[R=301]` in the first `RewriteRule` (the `.htaccess` equivalent of a `while` loop), but I couldn't get this working without creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. I also learned a few new things about mod_rewrite, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @proone Glad to help!